# Idea and preposition

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality, meaning-in-context, prepositions

I just need to have a better understanding of when and how to use the following prepositions with their corresponding word:

1. Idea about
2. Idea of
3. can you use the preposition “about” with the word “understand/understanding”?

Thank you!

Comment: This is potentially a very large topic. All of: - *about, of, with, from, on, in* - each in its own way, works with *idea* as well as *understand/understanding*.Can you provide some possible sentences for us to critique?

Comment: Also, simply searching a large database (eg Google, but there are corpora as well) for those collations will provide usages. Please edit your question to include the research you have done, the results you obtained and what the results still don't tell you.

Answer (score 1):

"Idea of" can be used when you want to spell out an idea.
example: The idea of having Jack as our employee was helpful.

"Idea about" can be used when you want to say an idea is about a subject, but not to mention the idea in detail.
example: Your idea about the new employment was helpful.